# Changing turtle 1's position changes turtle 2's position

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
def func():
    print("T POSITION: ", t.pos()) # prints 100, 100
    t2.pencolor("black")
    t2.setpos(0,0)
    print("T POSITION: ", t.pos()) # Now, prints 0, 0
    print("T2 POISTION: ", t2.pos())
```

both. `t.pos()` and `t2.pos()` are set to `(0,0)` , even though i declared as global variable t1 and t2 separately.

```
t= turtle.getturtle()
t.setpos(100,100)
t2 = turtle.getturtle().
```

If I only want to change the position of `t2`, to `0,0`, how could I accomplish this?

Comment: you need to show the global declaration and the code of `getturtle`.

Comment: @Aganju. `getturtle()` is a turtle built-in function to access the *default* turtle.  There are very few reasons to invoke it, and this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `copy.copy` the `t2`:

```
import turtle,copy
t= turtle.getturtle()
t.setpos(100,100)
t2 = copy.copy(turtle.getturtle())
def func():
    print("T POSITION: ", t.pos())
    t2.pencolor("black")
    t2.setpos(0,0)
    print("T POSITION: ", t.pos())
    print("T2 POISTION: ", t2.pos())
func()
```

And now you get the results of:

```
T POSITION:  (100.00,100.00)
T POSITION:  (100.00,100.00)
T2 POISTION:  (0.00,0.00)
```

Otherwise:

```
>>> t==t2
True
>>> t is t2
True
>>> id(t)
333763277936
>>> id(t2)
333763277936
>>> id(t) == id(t2)
True
>>>
```

They're the same objects!!! totally!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Now, let's say I want to delete what t2 has drawn, and do t2.clear(). Then it clears what t1 has drawn, too. Why does this happen and how could I solve this?

Comment: @Hellowhatsup Then change: `t= turtle.getturtle()`  to: `t = copy.copy(turtle.getturtle())`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, "Don't use `getturtle()`!"  It's not the function you want.  It's for accessing the singlular *default* turtle and is rarely needed/used.  Instead use `Turtle()` to get a new turtle:

```
import turtle

def func():
    print("T1 POSITION: ", t1.pos())
    t2.setpos(0, 0)
    print("T1 POSITION: ", t1.pos())
    print("T2 POSITION: ", t2.pos())

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.pencolor("red")
t1.setpos(100, 100)

t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t2.pencolor("green")

func()

t2.circle(100)

t2.clear()

turtle.done()
```

And you don't need to `copy.copy()` turtles.  If you want a brand new turtle, use `Turtle()`.  If you want a new turtle that's just like an existing turtle, call `.clone()` on that turtle, e.g. `t3 = t1.clone()`.